# rspec matcher on array argument similar to hash_including

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

In rspec you can test that a call to a method receives an argument that is a hash and includes certain keys, or key-value pairs. That is:

```
my_object.should_receive(:my_method).with(hash_including(:a => 'alpha'))
```

Is there anything available to accomplish a similar match with an array? Something that would look like?

```
my_object.should_receive(:my_method).with(array_including('alpha'))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this:

```
my_obj.should_receive(:my_method) do |arg|
  arg.should be_an_instance_of(Array)
  arg.should include('alpha')
end
```

Comment: Smart. This works well. I plan to write a custom matcher based on this to be able to write with(array_including...